# Placeholder and cursor alignment alignment in Textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, placeholder

I have one HTML 'form' containing text boxes, here we showing some placeholders(default text).

As per the requiremnet default text showing as center align.Once we center aligned the cursor also showing center itself.Is there any solution for showing cursor for starting itself(left alignment) and placeholder for center alignment.

Placeholder and cursor alignment

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override it by jquery

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#inputId').focus(function () {
            $(this).css('text-align', 'left');
        }).blur(function () {
            $(this).css('text-align', 'center');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I made some couple of changes as per my requirement. Its helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try this Dude.

Here is the  Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/f0xn3wjL/2/

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Dummy Text" >
```

Use this CSS

```
input{width:300px; text-align:center}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:green; }
input:focus{text-align:left; content:''}
```

Use this Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input').click(function(){
    //alert('hi');
    $(':input').removeAttr('placeholder');
    })


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-writing [bl2b's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25679090/3398732) with vanilla CSS

```
selector {
    text-align: center;
}

selector:focus {
    text-align: left;
}
```